# Two-column layout not in proper flow - sidebar should be secondary

Tags: css, word-wrap, sidebar

For the main page of our site we have a main intro content area and a right sidebar.

I wanted the main content text to "wrap" around the right-hand sidebar when the main content extends beyond the sidebar's height (which itself extends based on content).

Below is the css and markup I used to accomplish this (My apologies in advance for the *Lorum ipsum*, I am using this to show how the main content text "wraps" around the right sidebar):

```
#container { width:100%; position:relative; padding:0; }
#maintext {}
#sidebar { float:right; width:200px }

<div id="container">

    <div id="sidebar">
      <ul>
      <li>Secondary</li>
      <li>Secondary</li>
      <li>Secondary</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="maintext">
      <p>More important intro text appearing AFTER sidebar in HTML flow: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas  bibendum pharetra est eu aliquet. In lacinia est non augue egestas, nec  sodales felis euismod. Curabitur lacus enim, egestas quis pharetra non,  molestie ut nisi.</p>
      <p>Cras eleifend, ante non elementum rhoncus, odio metus  dapibus quam, eget aliquam risus odio et lorem. Suspendisse euismod urna  cursus ligula commodo ultrices. Integer vulputate ante eu lectus  consequat mattis. Donec tristique massa at lectus viverra congue.  Maecenas elementum justo vel pretium pulvinar. Phasellus at tortor  metus. Quisque at ligula metus. Nulla euismod ipsum sit amet ullamcorper  sollicitudin. Sed accumsan libero vitae magna fermentum aliquam. Nunc  nec nisi diam. Morbi iaculis bibendum rhoncus. Pellentesque sagittis  bibendum felis in gravida.</p>
    </div>  

</div>
```

Fiddle for the above: http://jsfiddle.net/Ezbd9/1/

The problem with this markup is that the sidebar appears contextually BEFORE the main content. I tried moving the `#sidebar` div so that it follows the `#maintext` div, but the result was that the sidebar simply appears below the main content, floating to the right all by itself. As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Fct8F/1/

Initially I didn't worry about this, but considering SEO and also my new responsive design to my site I am trying to find a way to get this same text wrapping effect but in proper flow (i.e. Main Content followed by Sidebar).

In short, I want to get the same visual result as the above code, but with the `#maintext` div BEFORE the `#sidebar` div in the HTML.